# With the 2019 UA Revised Artificer, can you choose to end an infusion on an item?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, artificer, duration, artificer-infusions

With the [2019 UA Revised Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf), can you choose to end an infusion on an item?

It's not super clear on if they can or can't. It says if you try to infuse something past your maximum number of infused items, the oldest one ends. But maybe I don't want to drop the *bag of holding* infusion, ya know? Spells can generally be dropped, so would infusions?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, but it's not perfectly smooth

Currently, as described, there are three ways to drop an infusion.

- You can die, and wait a few days.  This will cause you to drop all of them all at once, and also requires you do die and stay dead for a few days.  It's not a perfect solution.
- You can infuse enough items to exceed your maximum, thus causing your oldest to fall off the back end.  Since you can keep touching and keep reinfusing, you can easily decide whichever distribution you like every day.  Just re-infuse until you've dropped the ones you want to drop.  This is potentially problematic in the case where you have infusions (like your favorite Bag of Holding) that you don't want to drop for even a moment, but otherwise works quite well.
- On level-up, you can unlearn one infusion in favor of another, which instantly drops the infusion on whichever one you unlearned.  This has obvious limitations on frequency of use, but does let you drop any one infusion cleanly without disrupting any other.

### On the other hand, this is UA

UA is playtest material, and they generally won't have caught everything.  They haven't considered all of the edge cases.  If this is a real issue for you, you can, and should, consult with your DM about it (who should be paying careful attention to balance issues on all UA material to begin with, and adjusting as necessary for their personal campaign) and ask for the ability to decide which infusion you drop when infusing past your max at the end of a long rest.  It would be a convenience increase without meaningful power increase.  As a DM, I'd permit it.

Answer (score 0):

### No

As currently written, the only rule for creating a new infusion when you already have your maximum infusions is to automatically drop the oldest, so you can't simply choose to drop any infusion. This may change if/when the Artificer becomes official in a book release as it requires additional bookkeeping to track the order of infusions, and 5E generally frowns on such unnecessary complexity. In light of this, it is reasonable to house-rule that the artificer gets to choose which infusion would be dropped.

> You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long
>   rest; the maximum number of objects appears in the Infused Items
>   column of the Artificer table. **You must touch each of the objects**,
>   and each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time. *If
>   you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest
>   infusion immediately ends, and then the new infusion applies.*

However, as written, you have one additional option - at the end of each long rest, you can create up to your full number of infusions. Assuming all items you have previously infused are available to you (as you can lend them to others so they could be any distance from you), you could simply re-infuse them in the order you desire, so that if you do need to infuse a new item (or change an infusion on an existing item) at a later date for some reason, you would have some control over which infusion would be dropped.

You could also swap infusions when you level to drop an existing infusion of your choice, but this doesn't seem terribly effective and is not likely to meet your needs.