# Can the version of the Artificer class published in "Tasha's Cauldron of Everything" choose to end an infusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer, duration, artificer-infusions

**Is there an easy way for an Artificer to willfully end an infusion?**

One of the many problems I am seeing is that an infusion only works on non-magical items. But infusions cause items to become magical. So if I infuse my armor with Enhanced Armor and want to switch it to Resistant Armor, is there a direct path to do so?

---

[There is a version of this question here, but it deals with the UA version.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151181/38834) My question is specifically for the version published in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. The answers may be the same, but I think it should be clarified based on the new/updated rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ben Barden’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/151185/62294) to the UA version of this question remains correct for the officially published version of the Artificer in *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything*:

> #### Yes, but it's not perfectly smooth
>
> Currently, as described, there are three ways to drop an infusion.
>
> - You can die, and wait a few days.  This will cause you to drop all of them all at once, and also requires you do die and stay dead for a few days.  It's not a perfect solution.

This follows from this part of the [Infuse Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#InfuseItem-1131631) feature description (TCoE, p. 12-13):

> Your infusion remains in an item indefinitely, but when you die, the infusion vanishes after a number of days have passed equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of 1 day).

Ben Barden’s next point is:

> - You can infuse enough items to exceed your maximum, thus causing your oldest to fall off the back end.  Since you can keep touching and keep reinfusing, you can easily decide whichever distribution you like every day.  Just re-infuse until you've dropped the ones you want to drop.  This is potentially problematic in the case where you have infusions (like your favorite Bag of Holding) that you don't want to drop for even a moment, but otherwise works quite well.

This follows from this portion of the feature description:

> If you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest infusion immediately ends, and then the new infusion applies.

Ben’s third point:

> - On level-up, you can unlearn one infusion in favor of another, which instantly drops the infusion on whichever one you unlearned.  This has obvious limitations on frequency of use, but does let you drop any one infusion cleanly without disrupting any other.

Which explains this line from the feature description:

> The infusion also vanishes if you give up your knowledge of the infusion for another one.

Comment: The other problem with going around the circle reinfusing each item (point 2) is that it breaks all attunement on those items, as they briefly become nonmagical.  Not a problem if the artificer was using it personally, since they can auto-attune newly infused items; but annoying for anything the rest of the party was using.

Comment: I realize this is Ben Barden's arguments, not yours, but I think you could be more critical.  For example, I think of "when you die" as a trigger that doesn't require you to continually stay dead in order to have the triggered effect happen.  Likewise, it is not clear that just because you no longer know an infusion do the old infusions you prepared drop off - my reading is that they stay until your new ones exceed your total number.

Comment: I know this is late, but what about breaking/destroying the infused item?