# Can an artificer reset an infusion's charges by re-infusing it?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

Some artificer infusions have charges, like normal magic items. For example, the *mind sharpener* from TCE:

> The item has 4 charges. […] The item regains 1d4 expended charges daily at dawn.

However, artificers can also redo their infusions whenever they finish a long rest.

Suppose I, an artificer, have completely depleted my *mind sharpener*. I'd like to have a full stock of four charges for the next day. Can I let the infusion on the object end, and then re-infuse it, bringing it back to its initial four charges? In other words, are the rules for infusions regaining charges only for when they're away from the artificer, unable to be re-infused?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192462/can-the-version-of-the-artificer-class-published-in-tashas-cauldron-of-everyth)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically, this works; if the infusion ends and then gets reapplied, then the item is a brand new item. But there's a problem: you can't "let the infusion end". There's no such animal.

Infusions end when you die or exceed your infusion limit by making a new item, which ends the oldest infusion you have. You can go round-robin, reinfusing all your items in order to get back around to the one you actually wanted to reset, but that has some implications as well. All your items will momentarily cease to exist, so for example everything your *bag of holding* will spill out, and anything your allies had attuned to will become unattuned. (You can automatically attune *yourself* to newly infused items, but not your buddies.) Depending on your current loadout, this may be no big deal, or really annoying.